# select some columns of dataframe python pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has 10 columns.

I want to select some columns from it;  (first of two, and 9. column.)

```
x = df[['repo_id','user_id']]
y = df.iloc[:, [9]]
```

How can I concat them? (except "merge" function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it;

```
pd.concat([x, y], axis=1, sort=False)
```